# What should I do if the memory is insufficient when I use TPngImage to load a large image?

Tags: c++builder

What should I do if the memory is insufficient when using `TPngImage` to load a large image? A picture is about 2M, which is a 4K picture

It is necessary to draw a moving ball on the `TPngImage`. In order to realize this function, I frequently redraw the PNG image on the canvas, which will report insufficient resources. Is there a solution?

Error loading pictures:

```cpp
pic_qm->LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName)+"pic\\xl_xl\\png4k\\1\\4k1.png");
```

I redraw the background every 0.1 seconds, draw another moving ball:

```cpp
double g_qm_width=2160;
double g_qm_height=3840;
TRect myrect(0,0,g_qm_width,g_qm_height);
pForm_pg->Image_qmian->Canvas->StretchDraw(myrect,gqmGraphic);
pForm_pg->Image_qmian->Canvas->Ellipse(mX-20,mY-20,mX+20,mY+20);
```

Comment: *I frequently redraw the PNG image on the canvas* I believe this is the main problem. Instead draw the .png image once to a memory bitmap, then, every time you need to update the display, first `BitBlt` the area you need to update, from the in-memory bitmap to the canvas, and finally redraw the ball on the canvas. Search this site for `BitBlt` for inspiration and details.

Comment: Could you please write a simple code example? I don't know much about bitBlt. Also, I would like to ask TPNGImage to report errors when loading pictures. The picture is 2160*3840 pixels.

Comment: `TPngImage` is not a visual component, it is a `TGraphic` class used with `TPicture`, and thus the `TImage` component.  `TImage` is a `TGraphicControl` descendant, so I would probably just use a separate `TImage` or `TShape` and put it on top of the PNG image, and then animate the 2nd image as needed. Another option it is to use `TPaintBox` instead and just render the two images onto its `Canvas` in its `OnPaint` event